# Can't stay invisible on gtalk

Tags: instant-messaging, google-talk

Whenever I log in into GMail, its GTalk client tells me:

> Oops! You are not invisible because you're logged into Google Talk from another client, device, or location that doesn't support invisibility.

Steps I have taken to remedy this:

- I have enabled multifactor authentication on my Google Account.
- I have deauthenticated all other machines on the Google Account dashboard.
- I have clicked on "details" near "Last account activity: 1 minute ago" on the bottom right area of gmail's web interface and logged out of any other sessions.
- I do not have other GMail or Google+ tabs open when I experience this issue.
- I do not have Pidgin, Empathy or other jabber clients open when I experience this; additionally, my android phone is turned off as well as my home computer. I had an application specific password for Empathy and another for Xabber (an Android GTalk client) but removed them.
- I do not have GTalk browser extensions installed.
- I have changed my google password.

Despite all these steps, the issue persists.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think this would fit on webapps.SE as I use gtalk on multiple devices and platforms -- gmail's interface, g+ interface, ubuntu pidgin, ubuntu empathy, xabber (android client), official android client (pre-hangout update), official android client (post-hangout update), windows desktop client, official chrome extension, and maybe somewhere else.

Comment: related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44379/always-connected-in-gmail-chat

Comment: related: http://0-productforums.google.com.library.lanecc.edu/forum/#!topic/chat/9Q8w6C8cXd8

Comment: related: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chat/T1jvgnRSemo[1-25-false]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I thought I had removed both application-specific passwords I had created on my two-step authentication, but I had forgot to remove one (the one for xabber).

I hadn't had the app running on my android for days (even on background), my android wasn't on wifi nor 3G and I when troubleshooting the issue I turned the phone off.

Despite all that, when I removed the app. specific password from the google account list the issue was solved, I'm now invisible on gmail.